# syntax to use near 'ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)'

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, timestamp, sequelize.js

I want to use timestamp column `createdAt` -> `created_at`, `updatedAt` -> `updated_at`

and when I update any row, I wanna change column update_at to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

So I wrote like this,

```js
export const User = sequelize.define(
  'user',
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    name: { type: DataTypes.STRING(15), allowNull: false },
    nickname: { type: DataTypes.STRING(15), allowNull: false },
    email: { type: DataTypes.STRING(15), allowNull: false, unique: true },
    password: { type: DataTypes.STRING(15), allowNull: false },
    role: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(30),
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 'USER',
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: 'TIMESTAMP',
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
      field: 'created_at',
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: 'TIMESTAMP',
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal(
        'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
      ),
      field: 'updated_at',
    },
  },
  { timestamps: false }
);
```

Everyone say "`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`" it works.

When I update any column, Yes, It works.
but When I create any row, I can see error like this.

`sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)' at line 1",`

What's the matter?

Now, I use `sequelize@6.20.1` and `mysql2@2.3.3`.

And that is `DESC users;` table.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6tbK.png)

Comment: Enable general log on MySQL and look for complete SQL statement received. The part if it does not allow to detect the incorrectness.

Comment: *And that is DESC users; table.* DESC gives no complete information, provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` output instead of it always.

Answer (score 2):

I recently encountered the same syntax error while working with Sequelize, and it turns out it is quite common to run into this error for those who are new to Sequelize or shifting from SQL. The error can be resolved by ensuring the correct syntax.

**Instead of writing like a native SQL value** `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` **for updating the** `TIMESTAMP`  **:**

```
export const User = sequelize.define(
  'user',
  {
    .....
    createdAt: {
      type: 'TIMESTAMP',
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
      field: 'created_at',
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: 'TIMESTAMP',
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal(
        'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
      ),
      field: 'updated_at',
    },
  },
  { timestamps: false }
);
```

**Try the:** `onUpdate` option in sequelize which updates the `TIMESTAMP` upon updating values in a row.

```
export const User = sequelize.define(
  'user',
  {
    .....
    createdAt: {
      type: 'TIMESTAMP',
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
      field: 'created_at',
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: 'TIMESTAMP',
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.literal("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"),
      onUpdate: Sequelize.literal("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"),
      field: 'updated_at',
    },
  },
  { timestamps: false }
);
```

Hope this helps.